# How to SELECT in this schema?

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema

```
mysql> describe category;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | char(64)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe subcategory;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | char(64)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe quote;
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content        | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id    | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subcategory_id | tinyint(3) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from quote;
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
| id | content | category_id | subcategory_id |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
|  1 | text1   |           1 |              1 |
|  2 | text2   |           1 |              2 |
|  3 | text3   |           2 |              1 |
|  4 | text4   |           1 |              3 |
|  5 | text5   |           2 |              3 |
|  6 | text6   |           2 |              1 |
|  7 | text7   |           2 |              2 |
|  8 | text8   |           3 |              1 |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

First question is, should I drop the `quote.category_id` to have a normalized db?

More importantly,
I would like to

`SELECT quote.content WHERE the subcategory.name='some_name'`

How to archive this?

Sorry for the basic question but I am new to SQL. I guess this involves some kind of JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out that a way is:

```
select content, quote.category_id, quote.subcategory_id from quote, subcategory where subcategory.id=quote.subcategory_id and subcategory.name='some_name';
```

Comment: That would be a cross join

Comment: If you feel the category_id value is redundant, then yes you should drop it to normalize your table better.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count (1) as total, a.id, b.name
from options a, category b
where a.id =b.id
and a.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the category on the quote table since it already is contained in the subcategory table.

The basic syntax of your query would be:

```
Select q.* from quote q where q.subcategory_id IN (select subcategory_id from subcategory where name='NAME');
```

You can also do a join like so:

```
Select q.*, s.name from quote q
Left Join subcategory s USING(subcategory_id)
WHERE s.name='NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of information out there to answer your question. The [article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) has a number of references on DB normalization. From the schema you have, you could drop it to remove redundant information.

You are also correct about the `JOIN`. There is a nice [visual explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) himself.